# Managed entity cached in same request and not updating

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine-odm

> My code is fairly complex so I will try to explain in the simplest way possible

I have a parent entity `ValueList`. This 'list' has many `ValueListItems`.

```
class ValueList
{
  //...
  /**
   * @ODM\ReferenceMany(
   *   targetDocument="JobboardBase\Entity\ValueListItem", 
   *   sort={"order"="asc"}, 
   *   cascade={"all"}
   * )
   */
   protected $items;
}
```

I then have a service method that adds a new `ValueListItem` to this (already managed) `ValueList`.

```
public function createValueListItem(ValueListItem $item, ValueList $list)
{
  try {
    $om = $this->getObjectManager();

    $om->persist($item);
    $list->addItem($item);

    $om->persist($list);
    $om->flush();

    return $item;

  } catch (\Exception $e) {

    throw $e;
  }
}
```

This adds the entity correctly to the Mongo collection. However because I am executing the controller action with an AJAX call I also need to re-dispatch the 'indexAction' to return a the updated 'list' HTML asynchronously.

```
// ListItemController::createAndAttachValueItemToParentListAction()
// ....
// Below is the successful 'add' of the above method call return
if ($service->createValueListItem($form->getData(), $list)) {
  $content = $this->forward()->dispatch('JobboardBase\Controller\ListItem', array(
    'action' => 'index', 
    'id' => $list->getId()
  ));
  return $this->jsonModel(array(
    'success'  => true,
    'messages' => array($message),
    'content'  => $content
  )); 

//... IndexAction
public function indexAction() {
  // ...
  $items = $list->getItems(); // Returns 0 (when there should be 1)
  //...
}
```

The HTML returned via the `forward()` call (in `$content`) doesn't include the new added `ValueListItem` entity. It will however display correctly when I refresh the page.

Doctrine seems to be returning a cached `ValueList` entity that doesn't include the newly added `ValueListItem` - Only when a new requested is made does the new item get displayed.

My question is why is doctrine returning the 'old' entity rather than the updated entity? I was under the impression that it should be the *same* instance and therefore updated by reference?

Comment: did you try `$om->refresh($list)`?

Comment: @claustrofob Dam, No! Never saw `refresh()` in the docs! Having now searched a bit it does seems to be what i'm after - thank you (add an answer ;-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can refresh your model with the actual data using entity manager `refresh` method:

```
$om->refresh($list);
```